# Is there a way to set a default value for my Metadata Navigation and Filtering's Key Filters fields

Tags: 2013, development, managed-metadata, filter, metadata-navigation

I have a wiki pages library inside my SP on-premises 2013. And I have enabled the "Metadata Navigation and Filtering" site feature.
Then i went to my pages library setting >> Metadata navigation settings >> and i added 5 site columns which are of type Managed Metadata inside the "Configure Key Filters", as follow:-

[image]

here is the result

[image]

now i am trying to find a way to define default values for these key filters. i tried setting a defualt value for these site columns, but the defualt value will be shown when creating a new page, but will not have any effect on the key filter.. so is there a way to set a defualt value for my key filters??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter a value by default, I'd probably use the query strings as a default page link (for navigation or webpart header link) like this: `[...]/doclibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Doc%5Fx0020%5FStatus&FilterValue1=Archived` and add more filters with `FilterField2` and `FilterValue2`

Or if you are looking to add values to the textboxes, I'd use javascript on load to add whatever values you want to put.

Comment: thanks for the hint , now i chose the default value inside the "Key Filters" area, and i click on Apply button, where i got a new url containing the filtering criteria .. now i can use this url  to set the defualt value.. this worked well, although it will only allow me to chose a single filter value for each filter field, as when i define two values inside the same filter field,, the url will only contain the value for one value. not sure why ...